# ListView Disclosure Indicator Button - Xamarin Form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin platform and I have started implementing tutorials in Xamarin form (Cross Platform). I wonder how to implement an accessory which is disclosure indicator button on the ListView(tableView). I am attaching the screenshoot from XCode TableViewcontroller to make my question clearer.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Xamarin.Forms** you can customize your list view rows by using a **ViewCell**.

In the link [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/) towards the end there is a section on customizing **Xamarin.Forms** **ListView** control row layout.

In short you will have something like the following as a template in your **XAML** form:-

```xml
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
```

** Place your custom Xamarin.Forms markup here for customizing the display of your list row **

```xml
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>  
</ListView>
```

In the middle you can place any Xamarin.Forms markup to achieve the look that you are desiring.  So maybe use a **Grid** or **StackLayout** and customize the inner look.

Because you are using **Xamarin.Forms** you will have to create your own layout to achieve a similar effect.  Remember you are now targetting multi-platform.  If you really like the '>' look then perhaps create an image and add a **Xamarin.Forms Image** to achieve this effect?  I don't think you can add the various platform-specific accessories any other way without writing some kind of custom renderer.

Comment: Hello Pete, that makes sense. How could I add an image in this xaml? If you dont mind, could you please write a small script for adding image.

Comment: Here is a [guide](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/) for working with images.  In its simplest form you could write <Image Source="myImage.png" /> within the ViewCell.View.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can a toolbaritem, details here http://codeworks.it/blog/?p=232

Comment: Hello Corcav, I want to stick with ListView, I do not want to use toolbar item. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved the task as follow.

```html
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>

          <Grid BackgroundColor="White" Margin="10">

              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/> 
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>                                   
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
                  <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="startIcon.png" /> 
                  <StackLayout Grid.Column="1">
                      <Label 
                          Text="{Binding ProductName}"
                          Margin="8"
                          FontAttributes="Bold"
                          FontSize="Medium" />
                      <Label Text="{Binding Quantity}"
                          Margin="8,2,8,4"
                          FontSize="Small" />
              </StackLayout>  
              <Image Grid.Column="2" Source="rightIcon.png" />                          
          </Grid>    
      </ViewCell>                    
  </DataTemplate>                
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```